# Bounce webkit animation

Tags: css, animation

This is hard to explain, bit I'll give it a shot.

I currently have an image background that endlessly slides from right to left, like a conveyor belt. The image just repeats when it runs out.

I'm trying to to get the image/animation to bounce (reverse direction) before it repeats. So the image slowly slides one way, then slowly back the other way.

CSS:

```
#bg {
    -moz-animation: bg 60s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bg 60s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: bg 60s linear infinite;
    animation: bg 60s linear infinite;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);

    background: #348cb2 url("images/cns-lagoon-sunrise.jpg") bottom left;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

@-moz-keyframes bg {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes bg {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
    }
}

@keyframes bg {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(-2250px,0,0);
    }
}

#bg {
    background-size: 2250px auto;
    width: 6750px;
}
```

I've tried `animation-direction: alternate;` but that just reverses the whole animation :(

Before I bother my friend (again) for help, I though I'd reach out here. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you do 2D translation in only `x` direction, you can use `translateX` instead of `translate3d` for simplicity. But `translate3d` will work as well if you prefer.

To answer your question, I will show only standard css (withoud prefixes). You can easily add prefixes. Apply these changes:

```
@keyframes bg {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(-2250px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

I just copied the value `-2250px` from your code. You will probably need to adapt that value to your needs.

Comment: Thank-you! This works really well on my 1080x1920 display, but on other resolutions, it does all kinds of crazy things. http://exp.joshniesler.com.